# Why is it more crucial to consider velocity field than displacement field in Fluid Mechanics?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, velocity, flow, displacement

Why is it more crucial to consider velocity field rather than displacement field in Fluid Mechanics?

Comment: It is simpler in terms of the velocity field and does not depend directly on the displacement, but does depend directly on the velocity field.

Comment: @ChetMiller So it depends directly on velocity field since the displacements are large and complicated to be used in fluid equations?